# Паттерны реализации абстракции List<Interface>

Tags: c#, ооп

Приветcтвую, уважаемые!

Частенько возникает следующая ситуация:

```
//Есть интерфейс
interface INode
{
    //Который содержит список элементов, представленных интерфейсом
    List<INode> Parents { get; set; }
}

//Хочется реализовать этот интерфейс вот так
class Node : INode
{
    //Но так делать нельзя
    public List<Node> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

На ум приходит только такое решение:

```
interface INode<T> where T: INode<T>
{
    List<T> Parents { get; set; }
}

class Node : INode<Node>
{
    public List<Node> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

Но такое решение мне не особо нравится. Использование а-ля `Cast<T>` тоже не подходит.

Вопрос: знаете ли вы паттерны, которые разрешат описанную выше ситуацию?

Comment: А зачем вам в реализации именно `List<Node>`? Пишите также `List<INode>`

Comment: Ну вариант с T хороший, чем он вам не нравится?

Comment: Такая реализация предпочтительней, потому что я не нашел, как заставить EF понимать `List<INode>` как `List<Node>`. Вариант с `T` вполне рабочий, и я им пользуюсь, но мне интересно, может есть вариант лучше.

Comment: А если вместо интерфейса использовать абстрактный класс? Ну и почитайте про наследование в EF. Всё-таки здесь не поведение, а состояние, поэтому абстрактный класс здесь семантически уместнее.

Answer (score 1):

А вот так годится? https://ideone.com/xLqgjY

```
interface INode
{
  IEnumerable<INode> Parents { get; }
}

class Node : INode
{
  private List<Node> parents;
  public IEnumerable<INode> Parents { get { return parents; } }
}
```

Comment: Если интерфейс не требует наличия сеттера, то годится. Но в общем случае, увы, нет.

Comment: @Groxan, ну так в общем случае так и нельзя делать.

Comment: Я жеж привел пример, как можно сделать, чтобы работало =)

Comment: @Groxan, ну так ты же не так хочешь. А вот то, как ы хочешь, как раз и не получится)